# Is it possible to add dll to resources, and load that dll from resources with LoadLibrary? C++

Tags: c++, dll, resources, loadlibrary

I'm working on a keylogger. [Here](http://thetechnofreak.com/technofreak/keylogger-visual-c/) I found an implementation that loads current keyboard in runtime. The problem is that no keyboard libraries from win8 or win7 are loaded correctly. But I managed to find one US keyboard library that works fine.

So, now, I would like to add that library to resources and to use it when I'm loading keyboard.

My question is, how do I navigate to that resource dll when calling LoadLibrary()?

Comment: You can't, it must be a file on disk.  There's just no point in avoiding that, if it really needs to be a single file then name it setup.exe

Comment: Can you give me explanation on how do I make it a single file?

Comment: Surely you've ran a program called setup.exe before?  There are many utilities around that help you create an installer for your app.  A decent start point is Google, query "installer creator utilities".

Answer (score 1):

If you really want an exe instead of installer, you can bundle a dll as resource. ReadResource and write it to file disk(some temp path, such as appdata\local\temp); and then runtime load it, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the link about runtime load library; Finally you need to delete it.